# Where did the Levitical priesthood go?

Tags: history, kohen-priest, beis-hamikdash, korban, levites-leviyim

Has the sacrificial system of the Torah been abandoned? Do those in the Tribe of Levi still act as priest?

I have just never seen or heard of anyone making sacrifices of animals or going to a Tabernacle as it is described in the Torah.

Comment: [Cousin? 8^)] Todd, welcome to Judaism.SE, and thanks very much for bringing your curiosity here! I look forward to seeing you around.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Torah made it very clear ([Deuteronomy 12:5-18](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0512.htm#5)) that once the Jews would reach "the rest and inheritance ...the place G-d will choose" (i.e. the Temple in Jerusalem), that would be *the* place for sacrificial service. The Second Temple was [destroyed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Temple#Destruction) by the Romans around the year 70, and thus there haven't been sacrifices since. Thus, many of the roles of the Levites (and the Kohanim, a subset of them) haven't been available for quite some time.

There are a few ceremonies today still performed, however, though none as dramatic as animal sacrifice. A Kohen is given some money to ["redeem" a firstborn male child](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pidyon_haben), and a lamb to redeem a firstborn male donkey (okay that one isn't quite as common). Kohens and Levites are still accorded special honors in synagogue service (e.g. [getting called up to the Torah first](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torah_reading#Aliyot)), and participate in [blessing the people](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priestly_Blessing) as described in Numbers ([6:22-27](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0406.htm#22)).

Comment: Thanks for tackling this. This answer could be improved (by you or others, including maybe me later) by adding links to Scriptural references and sources for more information.

Comment: Agreed, Isaac. Hopefully later.

Answer (score -1):

Some observations I have come across. Since the Temple was destroyed in 70A.D. I believe the records some of not all were destroyed with. To be a Levitical priesthood, had to be proven be record...am I correct? Reference Ezra 2

Comment: This is not formulated as an answer to the question.

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya Scott. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Hope to see you around!